# Text color in button, rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, colors

I have a view of a rails app with that:

```
<%= link_to 'New Empleado', new_empleado_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
```

The problem is that the button have grey color text, and I want white text like when I use this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >New Empleado</button>
```

With the first line the color of text is grey and with the second one the text color is white, and I want always white color.

I have try to use:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ><%= link_to 'New Empleado', new_empleado_path%></button>
```

but in this case the text has also grey color

I'm using sb-admin2 bootstrap theme

Comment: What css declarations has the `btn-lg` class?

Answer (score 0):

http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/buttons.html

If that's the theme you're using, it looks like the buttons do have white text by default. You must have another stylesheet overriding that with grey. Inspect the button by right-clicking it in chrome and figure out where the grey is coming from in the styles tab.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles#styles

In Chrome, find the source of "color: grey" and then uncheck the box to confirm that changing it will work. Then just delete or comment out that line in your style sheet.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was mi scaffolds.scss